# WKWebView not showing image preview

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic4, wkwebview

I am building an app in Ionic 4. Recently, I've been working on trying to get the user to take a picture and upload it. I have followed the Ionic 4 images tutorial: https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-image-upload-storage/ . However, there is one problem I cannot seem to fix: whatever I try, as soon as the user took a picture with the camera or selected one out of the image gallery, the list that's supposed to provide a preview of the image does not display the image:https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aw4jL.jpg

I have already tried to get rid of node modules and app plugins, reinstalling those. I have also created an app from scratch, only implementing the tutorial - however, the same error showed up.

Not unimportant: when I run the app on iPhone DevApp using 'ionic serve --devapp', the image preview list does not add an item at all (the exact error is on the function `this.webview.convertFileSrc(img);`) and the following warnings are displayed:

```
[ng] [console.warn]: "Native: tried calling WebView.convertFileSrc, but the WebView plugin is not installed."
[ng] [console.warn]: "Install the WebView plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview'"
```

... which is also curious because that plugin is, in fact, installed (present in both node_modules and plugins of the iOS platform folder).

I've been stuck on this for a few weeks now. Any help would be immensely appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you solve it? I am stuck there too

Comment: @CarlosMontiel does it work when you build and run it on your phone (so not with Ionic Devapp)? Currently, my images still don't show up in devapp but when building for phone everything works as expected.

Comment: Hello, it doesn't I just changed to another way and it works